# Is it possible to get internet via wifi with one wifi card while using aircrack-ng with another?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux, aircrack-ng

I have two cards in my laptop, the internal card and then an external USB one. Is it possible to get internet through WiFi on one, and then use the other for aircrack-ng? The issue I'm having is that aircrack-ng is stopping `NetworkManager` in order to put the card in monitor mode, except that causes BOTH cards to lose access, and I want to keep one still connected. Is there any way to keep one connected to the internet?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need NetworkManager to connect to a wifi network; it's just a manager. If your wifi network uses WPA, you can connect using wpa_supplicant.

The `wpa_passphrase` command generates a minimal config for `wpa_supplicant`:

```
$ wpa_passphrase MYSSID passphrase
network={
    ssid="MYSSID"
    #psk="passphrase"
    psk=59e0d07fa4c7741797a4e394f38a5c321e3bed51d54ad5fcbd3f84bc7415d73d
}
```

You can run `wpa_supplicant` with this configuration in order to set up your adapter:

```
# wpa_passphrase MYSSID passphrase > myssid.conf
# wpa_supplicant -B -i my_interface -c myssid.conf
```

Finally, get an ip address:

```
# dhcpcd my_interface
```

If all went well, you should be connected on that interface.

[(source)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant)

Comment: I believe aircrack also stops WPA_supplicant but, I'll take a look at that when I get a chance.

Comment: you might be able to start it after starting ac-ng. as i recall, it shouldn't mess with other interfaces,  but i could be wrong.